# axios is not returning data from openweathermap api

Tags: node.js, api

I am trying to get data from openweathermap api. I am easily getting it using postman but I tried with nodejs with axios request and it is responding with 400 status code.
I have written following code for it-

```
try {
      let a = 'london'

      const data = await axios.get(
        `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${a}&appid=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}`
      )
      console.log('the data is', data)

      if (data) {
        console.log('the data is', data)
        res.status(201).json(data)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error.message)
      res.status(403)
      res.json(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `http://` or `https://` to the url. Without them the URL is incorrecly formatted and axios thinks it's a relative URL (e.g. `/local/api`) but because you try to execute it on node, it doesn't have a context for "relative" as it would in browser (Site origin).